# I found a stronghold, searched for more than an hour, but I CANNOT FIND THE END PORTAL!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft I use eyes of ender to locate a stronghold, but when I got there, there where only useless rooms and caves where cutting through it making it difficult to navigate, and me and someone else both searched for more than an hour but could not find the end portal. I threw eyes of ender inside the stronghold to try to find the portal room but that did not work. I am running out of eyes of ender, inventory space, and weapons. I managed to get more stone pickaxes by finding the library and wrecking the walls and using cobblestone I already have. I am playing in a server where ANY cheating is untolerated, so spectator or getting the world seed is not a choice. I did find some weird rooms that you have to wreck blocks to get in. I am running out of options.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: As fpr 'how you should proceed', find another stronghold, just travel far away enough that eyes of ender point to the new one instead of the broken one.

Answer (score 5):

## Strongholds don't necessarily have a end portal.

Here are some quotes about it:

> There's usually 3 strongholds per world and they don't all necessarily all have a portal
> <sub><sup>*- [Stronghold without end portal - Minecraft Forums](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft/discussion/2901673-stronghold-without-end-portal)*</sup></sub>

After doing some more digging i found out that Java doesn't always have portals and Bedrock occasionally produces strongholds without portals:

> There doesn't appear to be a portal at this stronghold. Although Java always has portals, Bedrock occasionally produces strongholds without portals.
> <sub><sup>*- [Strongholds with no end portals - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/8s4jpb/strongholds_with_no_end_portal/)*</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

Eyes of the ender are [useless](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Eye_of_Ender) for locating the end portal inside a stronghold:

> In Java Edition, the eye leads to near the spiral staircase that was the first room generated in the stronghold.
>
> In Bedrock Edition, eye of ender signal leads to 5 crossing room that was the second room generated in stronghold.
>
> In Legacy Console Edition, a thrown eye leads to a stronghold, but not exactly to an end portal.

While it is rare, it's possible in any version of Minecraft that the portal room got overwritten by a cave, a ravine or a mineshaft (even in Java Editions, where strongholds initially always generate with an end portal), in which case you have no other option but to find a different stronghold.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes strongholds get cut off by other underground structures (eg. ravines, mineshafts, etc.) there will be a stronghold, but sometimes, rarely, it won't even contain one room (eg. library, jail cells, etc.) the chances are really rare but its possible. the stronghold is basically useless. period.